# What are the 16 New Great People and 16 New National Wonders in Civ Rev 2.4.4?

Tags: ios, civilization-revolution

Civilization Revolution for the iPad was just updated with the following notice:

> **What's New in Version 2.4.4**
>
> Exciting new content has been added to enhance your Civilization experience including:
>
> - Purchase pack with 16 New Great People
> - Purchase pack with 16 New National Wonders

And, indeed, there are packs to purchase. But, what exactly *are* these new Great People and National Wonders? Even after purchasing the packs, there's no new *documentation*; I guess I could play 16 new games with each civilization to find out, but it would be kind of nice to know as part of my decision for picking my nationality at the start. I've looked online and can't find anything anywhere.